# Try to solve the following differential equation: $y''-4y=2\tan2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation:
$y''-4y=2\tan2x$

the Homogeneous part is:
$$y_h=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}$$
and I get according the formula:
$$C_1'e^{2x}+C_2'e^{-2x}=0$$
$$2C_1'e^{2x}-2C_2'e^{-2x}=2\tan2x$$

my questions is:

1. if $y_h$ is right?
2. how can I find $c_{1}$ , $c_{2}$ ?

thanks

Comment: you are finding $c_1$ and $c_2$ by initial condition

Comment: @user43687,thats what I did but I got integral was I cant to solve so I think I mistake in my way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok let us solve homogeneous part, we have

$y''-4*y=0$

or characteristic equation is $k^2-4=0$ from where $k_1=2$ and $k_2=-2$ , so homegenous solution we have

$y_p(x)=c_1*e^{2*x}+c_2*e^{-2*x}$

$c_1$ and $c_2$ can be found using initial condition, like $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=-1$ for example, about $y''-4*y=2*\tan(2x)$

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx

use this method, but I have checked wolfram alpha and it has not solution in particular solution in real functions

Comment: hi,first thanks you..I did your way and got integral: $$c2=\ 1.5* \int tan2x*e^{(2x)}$$ how can I solve it?

Comment: wolfram alpha showed me  that it has not  real solution,does this question has answers on book?i mean to check it? you can  denote $y=2*x$,  $dy=2dx$,so $dx=dy/2$ now put into first integral

Comment: the answer on the book is:
$$y=c1*cos2x+c2*sin2x-xcos2x+ln(cosx*sin2x)$$
so maybe yh is mistake?

Comment: you may get some mistake in $c_2$ calculation,please check again

Comment: ,I chack it again and I get the same answer..

Comment: it is not well defined integral,try to integrate by part

Answer (score 2):

What you have done so far is correct. You should proceed as follows:

Write the last two equations as a system

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{2x} & e^{-2x}
\\
e^{2x} & -e^{-2x}
\end{array}\right)
\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} C_{1}^{\prime}
\\
C_{2}^{\prime}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0
\\
\tan(2x) \end{array}\right)$$
Invert the matrix on the LHS to get
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
C_{1}^{\prime}
\\
C_{2}^{\prime} \end{array}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-e^{-2x} & -e^{-2x}
\\
-e^{2x} & e^{2x}\end{array} \right)\cdot \left( \begin{array}{c}
0
\\
\tan(2x) \end{array}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
-e^{-2x}\tan(2x)
\\
e^{2x}\tan(2x) \end{array} \right)$$
This gives you a system of first order equations which you can solve by integrating. However, its not a particularly nice integral.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem for ode's a solution exists (at least locally). Wolfram may not be able to explicitly calculate the integral, but there is a solution.

Comment: but how to integrate $tan(2*x)*e^(2*x)$,if we denote $y=2*x$ then   $dy=2*dx$,from there  $dx=dy/2$,do   we have 1/2*$tan(y)*e^{y}$,we may integrate by part,and is there integral of this function in real variables?

Comment: yea, I can't think of a good way to explicitly evaluate the integral. By parts seems hopeless.